# Yii error load css when using manage url

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii-url-manager

I have folder resource containing css file. I using registerCssFile and registerScriptFile to load them in components/Controller. I have a trouble when using manage urlManager in config/main . My Page can't load file css and javascript because link change follow controller id.

This is error:

> Controller  site : 
>   http://localhost/admin/site/resources/css/profile.css  ........
>   controller user :
>   http://localhost/admin/user/resources/css/theme-blue.css  ........

Please help me. 
Thank all so much.

Comment: Can you show the code. How are you registering CSS file.

Comment: This is my code :                                                                                                    $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;

            //Register css file
            $cs->registerCssFile('resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css');
            $cs->registerCssFile('resources/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css');
            $cs->registerCssFile('resources/css/theme-blue.css');
            $cs->registerCssFile('resources/css/profile.css');

Comment: Try "$cs->registerCssFile('/resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css');" with a / in front of path